# Trouble updating entries in .json file

Tags: python, json, kivy

This may seem basic but I'm into the basics of Python currently and I'm at a blockade I can't quite get past. I'm building a practice app using Python and Kivy which has a simple login system with a JSON file. So far, this app is almost entirely functional except for one function; forgot password.

I need to get the app to find if the user has entered a correct username so they may change their password (It's very basic but only a test, not a real application). There's a sign-up page that works and I've used similar code but I can't get it to update.

**I'll show the forgot password class below:**

```
class  ForgotPasswordScreen(Screen):
    def pass_update(self, uname, npword):
        with open('users.json') as file:

            users = json.load(file)
    if uname in users == users[uname]:
         
        users["password"] = npword

        with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(users, file)

        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right' 
        self.manager.current = "password_changed_screen"
    else:
        self.ids.wrong_password.text: "Username not found"
```

**Here is the code for the signup class:**

```
class SignUpScreen(Screen): #The usernames are stored in a .json file
    def add_user(self, uname, pword):
        with open('users.json') as file:
            users = json.load(file) #Locates the username details
    

    users[uname] = {'username': uname, 'password': pword,
        'created': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}#Year, month, day, hour, minute, second

    
    with open("users.json", 'w') as file:
        json.dump(users, file) #Creates a whole new file with the exisiting and added users
    self.manager.current = "Sign_up_complete"
```

**This is an example from the json file of one user:**

{"user1": {"username": "user1", "password": "password1", "created": "2020-07-07 00:16:28.293901"}

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: The code I implemented doesn't' update the dictionary in the json file, I'm not sure what I'm missing. It should update the password connected to the correct user but because I'm new to coding I must be missing something